# URI formats are not supported when read file into bytes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am making API in asp.net Web API framework. I want to read file and convert  it into bytes and return it to client.But when reading the file, exception occurs, URL format is not supported?
URL with fileName is send by client.I want to get the file from this URL and convert it into bytes. Tell me about , how i do this?

```
  [Route("api/product/v1/displayimage")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    //[GZipCompression]
    public async Task<byte[]> DisplayImage([FromBody] FilesVM model)
    {
        try
        {
            var UrlBase = Url.Content(model.BaseURL);

            //var UrlBase = Url.Content("~/Images/Users/5-signs-march14");
            // MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
            //string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
            byte[] byteInfo = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(UrlBase);
            return await Task.FromResult(byteInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's good to be extra careful if you're allowing the client to specify a path and then using that path to return a file. That could allow clients to request files you don't want them to receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Url.Content only returns a string (http://localhost/Image...). If you want the actual content you will have to download it. Here's an example:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(client.DownloadData(Url.Content("~/Images/Users/5-signs-march14")));
        }
```